# Click event not trigger when adding HTML dymanically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  adding a  link button on page load

Like

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav_container").append('<a id="testID" href="#">Click on me</a>');

    $("#testID").bind("click",function(){
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

But  Alert is  coming on click of Link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for dynamically added DOM elements, you'll need to use `.on()` as following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#testID', function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#nav_container").on("click","#testID",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically elements, we should use $.on as suggested by others. But in your case, it should work without using $.on. The reason it does not work it your case because of `<a>` tag default action to reload, try `event.preventDefault();`

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav_container").append('<a id="testID" href="#">Click on me</a>');

    $("#testID").bind("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

Or better as suggested by others to use $.on:

```
$("#nav_container").on('click', '#testID', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
});
```